# MVC Spring controller - ajax Not working properly

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have a MVC Spring controller. I call this ajax on page load.

```
$.ajax({
        type:       "get",
        url:        'custom/topic',
        data:       "email1=" + email1 + "&email2=" + email2 ,

        async:   false,
        success:    function(result) {
                    alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, error) {
            window.alert('description' + desc);
            window.alert('error' + error);
        }
    });
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/topic", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String topic(
            @RequestParam("x1") String x1,
            @RequestParam("x2") String x2) {

    System.out.println("test");
    String result1 = custom.topic(x1, x2);

    return "test";
```

In success for alert(result), it prints the whole code of the page.

Comment: Can you show your context configuration ? Since your are using ResponseBody only the result string should be outputted.

Comment: If I remove the @responseBody it still has same issue.

Comment: The result is String.

Comment: Also if I remove the @responseBody and just return a string in the controller. The same issue occure!

Comment: What is "result" equal to ? The exact string would be sent to the client.

Comment: Now result doesn't exist any more but the ajax call still print the whole code of the page.

Comment: I think your url is invalid? did the AJAX call hits to `topic()`? and what is `x1` and `x2` where you passing that data?

Comment: yes, there is no not found error. If I change the url, it says not found.

Comment: did the SYSO outputs test prints in console earlier?

Comment: There is nothing in console. It seems that it doesn't go to controller.

Comment: yes, you should give correct url in ajax call.. and also @RequestParm you have to change..

Comment: but when I change the url it says not found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49525/discussion-between-rembo-and-mark)

Answer (score 0):

you AJAX url and `topic` method signature is invalid,

do like:

if you have `@RequestMapping(value="/topic", method=RequestMethod.GET)` and if you class level mapping `@RequestMapping(value="/customprop")` don't forgot to add that too..

then define the GET url in form action tag like:

```
 <c:url value="/customprop/topic" var="getUrl"/>
  <form action="${getUrl}" id="tellfriendform" method="GET">
```

and in your AJAX call retrieve the url like:

```
$('#tellfriendform').submit(function(e){
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
              {
                type: "GET",
                url: formURL,
                data: postData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error:function(e){
                    alert('error: '+e);
                }
              });
            e.preventDefault(); // STOP default action
            e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });
```

and you should change the topic method signature like:

As you using Spring 3.0.4:
then, you GET should look like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/topic", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String topic(HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response){
     System.out.println("test");
     String email = request.getParameter("email");
     String email2 = request.getParameter("email2");
     String result1 = custom.topic(email, email2);

     return email+ ", "+email2;
}
```